# BGL graph with map on edges list

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, boost-graph

I'm trying to create some specific structure with Boost Graph Library.
I need to have nodes (vertexes) with input and output ports. Each ouput port could be connected to any input port of other node. I want to be able to check if specific output or input port is connected to any other port.

The idea is to use std::map as OutEdgeList inside of adjacency_list.

According to: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:choosing-graph-type
I'm only able to select one of std::vector, std::list, std::slist, std::set, std::multiset and std::hash_set.
(you can choose mapS as a type but it is implemented as std::set and I cannot get the value by key)

And I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to use std::map? If yes how?
2. How can I iterate throught inputs of vertex when using std::map?
3. If the above is impossible, how can I implement structures that
   suits the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally switched to [Lemon  graph library](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) which is not as hacky as BGL

Comment: The bad about BGL is that is not very much used, to many of the issues one faces during code writing is that not many examples are present.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see reasons why map cannot be used as data structure to store outgoing edges. Map has iterators that work in the similar way to say `std::vector`, etc. To handle incoming edges you will need 2 maps on each vertex. AFAIK BGL supports both lists on vertexes.

I would recommend you to modify (hack) BGL and see what will happen. The change might be not small. You will have to provide adjacency_list specializations for your new type of container. Most likely this will work.